# Application_Error firing even for handled exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, webforms, global-asax, application-error

I have some code to display a button if a URL exists:

```
try
{
    string dashboardURL = Config.RootUrl + "/Dashboard/Default.aspx";
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(dashboardURL);
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    btnDashboard.Visible = true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    btnDashboard.Visible = false;
}
```

However, when debugging, `req.getResponse()` causes `Application_Error` to fire.  I checked the exception being caught here and it is a `System.Net.WebException`.  My understanding was that `Application_Error` is fired for unhandled exceptions.

If I change the code to force an exception as follows:

```
try
{
    string dashboardURL = Config.RootUrl + "/Dashboard/Default.aspx";
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(dashboardURL);

    int j = 0;
    int i = 1 / j;

    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    btnDashboard.Visible = true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    btnDashboard.Visible = false;
}
```

then `Application_Error` is not fired, which is good.  Is there something particular about handling errors with `GetResponse()` that always causes `Application_Error` to fire, even if the exception is handled?

Comment: are you sure above exception is caught?

Comment: As the name implies 'Application Error' is an error issued at the application level.

Comment: Is `Config.RootUrl + "/Dashboard/Default.aspx"` in the same server/application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `/Dashboard/Default.aspx` in the same server/application?

If so then processing of that request can cause an error that will be captured by the `Application_Error`. The reason is that by doing `GetResponse()` you are doing a HTTP request, and any exceptions that happen while processing the request on (potentially) remote server will not be handled by try/catch on the calling code. In your special case remote server = local server, but the idea does not change.

Answer (score 2):

In Application_Error check the exception:

```
var exception = Server.GetLastError();
```

It is impossible that Application_Error is fired with this code.
Your exception must be after this try/catch Block.

Also try to Clean and Rebuild your solution, or force the Designer File to get recreated (Change something on aspx file).

I tested your code on different ASP.NET Version, even on MVC3/MVC4 Environment and Application_Error is never fired!